# Unable to select from SQL Database tables using node-ibm_db

Tags: node.js, db2, ibm-cloud

I created a new table in the Bluemix SQL Database service by uploading a csv (baseball.csv) and took the default table name of "baseball".

I created a simple app in Node.js which is just trying to select data from the table with `select * from baseball`, but I keep getting the following error:

```
[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT] SQL0204N "USERxxxx.BASEBALL" in an undefined name
```

Why can't it find my database table?

Comment: `"baseball"` is not the same as `baseball` when we're talking table names. Try the uppercase `BASEBALL` when creating the table. Alternatively, try `select * from "baseball"`.

Comment: This might be relevant: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65818/db2-query-error-sql0204n-even-with-the-schema-defined

Comment: @mustaccio that was it!  I thought it was case insensitive, but wrote the query in lowercase just in case.  Now I realize that the client will auto-capitalize it unless its quoted.  Please convert your comment to an answer and claim your prize :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the table from SQL Database web UI in bluemix and took the default name of *baseball*.  It looks like this creates a case-sensitive table name.

Unfortunately for me, the sql_db libary (and all db2 clients I believe) auto-capitalizes the SQL query into `"SELECT * FROM BASEBALL"`

The solution was to either

A. Explicitly name my table *BASEBALL* in the web UI; or

B. Modify my sql query by quoting the table name:

```
select * from "baseball"
```

More info at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0203adamache/0203adamache.html#N10121

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems independent of bluemix, rather it is usage error.

This error is possibly caused by following:

The object identified by name is not defined in the database.

**User response**

Ensure that the object name (including any required qualifiers) is correctly specified in the SQL statement and it exists.

try running "list tables" from command prompt to check if your table spelling is correct or not.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00204n.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-6-27-0-130